# In hybris commerce Attribute Descriptor there is don't copy flag. What is used for dontcopy flag?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, commerce

On a custom  development we are using VariantAttributeDescriptorModel to retrieve some information base on a flag. In that developing we have seen that dontcopy flag is never used or setted so we guess to try to use it to has a flag that made our logic triggered.
We have looked if that flag has some used inside Hybis Commerce (version 2005) but we not found what is the porpose of that flag. So let our know if it's used? Has some kind of porpose that Attribute Descriptor flag(DONTCOPY)?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It's used as a flag to add the attribute to a blacklist for syncing. You wouldn't normally set it but could be used to avoid syncing generated attributes that are persisted to the database. There's no point in syncing an attribute that is going to be overwritten by another part of the process.

If you search for the property in the platform Hybris types you'll see that it is used on the `ProductFeature` type in `catalog-items.xml` on the `valueType`, `stringValue`, `booleanValue`, `numberValue`,`rawValue` attributes. These are all set by the dynamic attribute handler on `ProductFeature.value`.

You can see what is going on in the class `ProductFeatureValueAttributeHandler`

It's the same effect as setting a `SyncAttributeDescriptorConfig` to disable syncing of an attribute for a sync job but built into the model itself so it will apply to all sync jobs.